# Firestore action in Android gets me a nodejs error about headers already sent

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, webview, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a webview to show content. The server is nodejs. When I request a page it works properly, but accessing firestore throws an error like nodejs is trying to send a page again.

Here is android webview where I am loading the page:

```
package com.utilityavenue.logintest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MyServices extends UAActivity {
    private WebView wvMyServices;
    private String providerID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_services);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(b != null) providerID = b.getString("providerID");
        wvMyServices = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvMyServices);
        wvMyServices.clearCache(true);
        wvMyServices.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wvMyServices.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        wvMyServices.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wvMyServices.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wvMyServices.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        JSInterface jsInterface = new JSInterface(this);
        wvMyServices.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "app");
        wvMyServices.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
        wvMyServices.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wvMyServices.loadUrl('myservices');
    }

}
```

Class UAActivity has the JS interface.

I can load other pages without issues. However, when I try to do some firestore action, either from android or nodejs, it looks like nodejs is sending headers again.
This JS code running on loaded page:

```
$('.service-status').on('click',function(){
    var newStatus = 1;    
    var serviceID = 'kdgduhguhoisdljiwe';
    window.app.setServiceStatus(serviceID,newStatus);
});
```

and this is JS interface method being called.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void setServiceStatus(final String serviceID,final boolean newStatus){
    uaDB.collection("services").document(serviceID).update("Status",newStatus);
}
```

If I try to do it from nodejs, calling it with a post instead JS interface, the same happens

```
app.post('/setservicestatus',function(req,res){
    db.collection('services').doc(req.body.serviceID).update({Status: req.body.status});
    db.collection('services').doc(req.body.serviceID).get().then(function(doc){
        var docData = doc.data();
        var newStatus = (docData.Status == true) ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
        res.json({ status: newStatus });
    });
});
```

This is the error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:494
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:501:3)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:211:21)
    at C:\Apps\ua\uaserver.js:231:9
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
```

uaserver.js:231 is where page was sent to the browser

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    'Content-Length': page.length,
    'Expires': new Date().toUTCString(),
    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
});
res.write(page);
res.end();
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.

When I grab the data from Firestore, a listener is created. Because I didn't cancel the listener, it was triggering uaserver.js:231 again.

To cancel the listener, Firestore returns a function:

```
var myUnsubscriber = serviceList.onSnapshot(coll => {...
```

then just execute the function and that listener will be canceled:

```
myUnsubscriber();
```

Hope it helps!